# JAVA Criteria API I need to get the Time Passed From a specfic Date

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need to select all the available records in database where creation date only passed 5 days
for more description .
I need to get all orders that time passed after creation 1 day or 2 days.

I mean can I subtract the creation date from the current date in the predicate object and then check if it equals the time passed or not.

```
int passedDays = 5;
Page<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll(new Specification<Order>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Order> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        // where created - now date = passedDays 
        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.<Date>get("createdAt"),passedDays));
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    }
},pageable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `between` Restriction:

```
int passedDays = 5;

@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<AuditTrail> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                         CriteriaBuilder cb) {

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Instant then = now.minus(passedDays, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    
    predicates.add(cb.between(root.get("createdAt"), then, now));

    // if your createdAt has type java.util.Date or java.sql.Date
    // predicates.add(cb.between(root.get("createdAt"), Date.from(then), Date.from(now)));

    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));            
}
```